# 1080p tapes converted to 480p question

Tags: video-editor

I have some 1080p video tapes that when converted were scaled down to 480p. The company I paid to do the conversion threw away the tapes. Is there any way to get back some of the quality? I'm willing to pay whatever it takes if it is possible. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, there isn't anything you can do to get back to the higher resolution. Once downconverted, the higher resolution information is lost.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, no.

As  Michael commented, to get to lower resolution, all that higher resolution data has been discarded. There is nowhere to get it back from.

Answer (score 0):

By some magical video upscaling, or reimagination using AI this can be done, as seen from an [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vj6C4UxDg3s) by [Topaz Labs](https://topazlabs.com/video-enhance-ai/).